# c# map server to android client push notification architecture

Tags: c#, android, .net, maps, push-notification

What will be the best way, architecture, protocol, service etc
to implement a the following system:
a map server side written in c# and android client,
the client sends their location to the server and the server send to all clients location updates.

So far i investigated the following technologies:
REST and BusQueue.
is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of BusQueue.
The way I see it, is that the android client should send the updates to the server through http requests. 
Now concerning the server, it depends on when the updates are required...if the android client requires the updates then again it should be an http request-response. 
On the other hand if the server knows when the updates should be sent, you should consider using Google cloud messaging (more details [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)).
If you decide using cloud messaging you will have several implementation options, like:

- Using messages with or without payload
- Using http, or xmpp

Finally for the communication you could also check android libraries [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) and [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) .